# doubling Array size if full

Tags: java, arrays

I have an array of objects. When the array fills up, I want to make a new array twice as large as the old one, and transfer all the elements over. I'm doing something wrong, I think its something to do with I'm not creating the correct reference to the new array. Here's my code, any help figuring this out would be appreciated.

```
    private int DIRECTORY_SIZE = 6; 
Entry [] directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE];
private int numberOfElements = 0;

public int getNumOfElements(){
    return numberOfElements;
}

public void setDirectorySize(int size){
    DIRECTORY_SIZE = size;
}

public int getDirectorySize(){
    return DIRECTORY_SIZE;
}




public void addEntry(String surname, String initial, String num) {
    // TODO add an entry to an array, also increments numberOfElements variable tracking whats in array 

    if(getNumOfElements() == getDirectorySize()){    // if array is full
        doubleArraySize();     // put temp values into new bigger directory array

    }

    int i = findFreeLocation();     
    directory[i] = new Entry(surname, initial, num);
    numberOfElements++;
}


private void doubleArraySize(){
    Entry[] temp = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE];  //make new temp array same size as old one
    for(int i = 0; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE ; i++){
        temp[i] = directory[i];                   // cycle through array putting all values into temp
                                                // works up to here
    }

    setDirectorySize(DIRECTORY_SIZE*2);             // double size of array


    Entry[] directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE]; // create new, double size directory array
    for(int i = 0; i < temp.length ; i++){
        directory[i] = temp[i];   
    }

}

 private int findFreeLocation() {

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < DIRECTORY_SIZE; i++) 
    {           
        if(directory[i] == null)
        { 
            break;
        }
    }
    return i;
}
```

Comment: Out of curiousity, why are you reinventing this wheel? `ArrayList` grows (not doubles, IIRC it does the 150% thing) as necessary, why not use that?

Comment: "I have an array of objects. When the array fills up, I want to make a new array twice as large as the old one, and transfer all the elements over" - are you aware that that's basically what `ArrayList` does?

Comment: Also, VARIABLE_NAMES_IN_CAPITALS are usually constants - in your case, DIRECTORY_SIZE is *not* a constant. This is pretty confusing.

Comment: Can you give us some example input/output? If you put "sally" and "jim" into the array of size 2 and try to add "john", what is in the array after your add operation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In doubleArraySize() function , this is the issue  :

```
 Entry[] directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE];
 // you are not assigning it to the class attribute directory
 // instead you are creating a local array directory
```

Make the following change :

```
 this.directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE]; 
// this will assign the newly created array to the class attribute
```

***Note :*** I personally prefer to use this pointer to refer to class attributes so that it makes my code more readable, and its clear to everyone that the variable in question is a class attribute rather than local variable.

**SIZE has already double by this point. No need to multiple by 2

Comment: Many thanks. I had a feeling it was something like that but I couldn't track it down

Answer (score 0):

I remember doing something exactly like this when I was making a Vector ADT. However, I used instance variables instead of methods in my code for element number and the capacity. I definitely didn't initialize a Vector inside a method for a Vector.

```
setDirectorySize(DIRECTORY_SIZE*2);             // double size of array


Entry[] directory = new Entry[DIRECTORY_SIZE]; // create new, double size directory array
```

Isn't DIRECTORY_SIZE an instance variable? Because if it is, I don't think you can initialize an object using an instance variable from the object you are overwriting.

Putting my code into your context, it would look something like this:

```
private void doubleDirectorySize()
{       
    Entry[] new_array = new Entry[new_directory_size*2];
    for (int i = 0; i < directory_size; i++)
    {
        new_array[i]= directory[i];
    }
    directory= new_array;
}
```

This only works if directory was initialized to null, though, moving the pointer directory to the new array.